# Severity: Notice --> Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop, codeigniter-2

i could not found the solution for this problem: *Severity: Notice  --> Trying to get property of non-object*

Please help me to find out my mistakes.

my model method:

```
  function get_AllDays_by_templateRoutine_id($rid) 
{ 
    $this->load->database(); 
    $this->db->select('day_id');
    $res =  $this->db->order_by('day_id', 'DESC')->get_where('template_user_days', array('routine_id'=> $rid));
    $ret = array();

    foreach ($res->result_array() as $row) {
        $ret[] = $row['day_id'];
    } 
    return $ret; 
}
```

& my controller

```
public function install_template()
{ 
      $rid = $this->input->post('rid'); 
      $userid=$this->session->userdata('userid');

        $urid=$this->routinemodel->getMaxUserRoutineId($userid);//method returning one value  

      $userdays_template=$this->templateroutinemodel->get_AllDays_by_templateRoutine_id($rid); 
       if(is_array($userdays_template)) 
        {
          foreach ($userdays_template as $row2) 
             {  
                    $day_value=$row2['day_id'];//Error:--> Trying to get property of non-object**
             }
         }    
}

                                 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use

```
$day_value = $row->day_id;
```

UPDATE:

```
$userdays_template=$this->templateroutinemodel->get_AllDays_by_templateRoutine_id($rid); 

for($x=0;$x<count($userdays_template);$x++)
{
  for($y=0;$y<count($userdays_template[$x]);$y++)
  {
    echo $userdays_template[$x][$y]->day_id;
  }
}
```

i just noticed you were returning an array of object instead of just objects here

```
foreach ($res->result_array() as $row) {
    $ret[] = $row['day_id'];
}
```

if it does not work, can you type in the result you were supposed to get?

Comment: Sorry still the same error message. I used `$day_value = $row->day_id;` by replacing  `$day_value=$row2['day_id'];`

Comment: I updated my code above with `update`, plz check it.  Explanation:  i written `echo("---userdays_template---------".var_dump($userdays_template)); //OUTput:  array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "959" [1]=> string(3) "958" }`      But this line is not printing -->`echo("---day---------".$day_value);//not printing the this line,why?`

Answer (score 2):

try this

if your $userdays_template is an object then use

```
 $day_value=$row2->day_id;
```

if your $userdays_template is an array then use

```
if(isset($row2['day_id'])){
 $day_value=$row2['day_id'];
}
```

Comment: Sorry! Still the same error message is comming. I used `$day_value = $row->day_id;` by replacing  `$day_value=$row2['day_id'];`                                  Please check my both methods code once again, may be i am doing any mistakes on them

Comment: have you used isset()?

Comment: Yes i have used but i do'nt know whether the value is coming or not... Please check the above code, i kept the new code in `update` section

Comment: you have again done mistake foreach ($userdays_template as $row) {  , instead of $row please write $row2

Comment: I updated once again, plz check it.  Explanation:  i written `echo("---userdays_template---------".var_dump($userdays_template)); //OUTput:  array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "959" [1]=> string(3) "958" }`      But this line is not printing -->`echo("---day---------".$day_value);//not printing the this line,why?`